# how to store json object in a variable and use globally in other functions in swift

Tags: json, swift, func

var drivers : NSArray?

```
func loadDriversREST()  {
           RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getDriverList{ json in
            var drivers = json
            println(drivers.description)

    }
```

func  getDriverFromId(id: Int?) -> String {

```
    if id == nil {
        return "No Driver Assigned"
    }
    else{
        drivers.["name"] as! String

    }
    return "test"
}
```

Comment: You could use NSUserDefaults()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what actually you want to do, but there are a lot of options.
You can use NSUserDefaults(). I did that in my case with user's domains:

```
private let DOMAIN_PREFIX = "DOMAINS_"
private let DOMAIN_DELIMITER = "|"
private let defaults: NSUserDefaults

init() {
    defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
}

func getDomains(user: String) -> [String] {
    if let domains = defaults.valueForKey("\(DOMAIN_PREFIX)\(user)") as? String {
        return domains.componentsSeparatedByString(DOMAIN_DELIMITER)
    }
    return [String]()
}

func saveDomains(domains : [String], user: String) {
    defaults.setValue(DOMAIN_DELIMITER.join(domains), forKey: "\(DOMAIN_PREFIX)\(user)")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

You can save your drivers in the save way.

Comment: i want to use variable drivers globally which is in loadDriversREST(). how can i do that?

Comment: my Json object drivers:{"name" : "vitalii",
    "licenseNumber" : "124841"}

Comment: If you just want to store this var globally you can write `static` keyword before `var drivers : NSArray?`. And than call it like `YOUR_CLASSNAME.drivers!`

Comment: How to iterate an AnyObject which is optional because it is throwing AnyObject does not have a member named Generator. I have already unwrapped it. Any example please?